# Updating newt (snack.py) interface from separate python thread

Tags: python, monitor, whiptail

The first time I update the list it works just fine, from the timer I get an unselectable copy of the last text item, i.e. two "forth", but only one of them working. I would like to update my newt interface asynchronously, but I am running out of ideas. Thank you.

[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKabr.png)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals
from snack import *

import subprocess
import time, threading

def time_counter():
    global li
    global screen
    li.replace("PROBLEM below",2)
    screen.refresh()

screen = SnackScreen()

li = Listbox(height = 35, width = 160, returnExit = 1)
li.append("First", 0)
li.append("Second", 1)
li.append("Third", 2)
li.append("Forth", 3)

bb = ButtonBar(screen, (("Ok", "ok"), ("Cancel", "cancel")),1)

g = GridForm(screen, "My Test", 1, 4)
g.add(li, 0, 0)
g.add(bb, 0, 3, growx = 1)

threading.Timer(2, time_counter).start()

li.replace("WORKS FINE",2)

g.runOnce()
screen.finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly deleting and reinserting an item does work in principle, but as the on-screen order gets messed up after a few iterations, not really.

So, just clear the whole list, update item and recreate.

```
box_list = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Forth"]
...
cur=li.current()
box_list[cur]="NO PROBLEM"
li.clear();
for idx, val in enumerate(box_list):
  li.append(val, idx)
li.setCurrent(cur)
```